# the navbar button are not working when I click on they just work when i click open in new page

Tags: javascript, css, jsx

The navbar buttons are not working. When I click on them, they just work when I click open in a new page.

```
export default class DefaultNavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar-fixed-top">
                <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="/">GatherUp</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav>
                            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">Home</NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/event">Event</NavItem>
                            <NavItem eventKey={3} href="/signup">Sign Up</NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any type of router? Also what is the Navbar component? If that's something you created can you share the code? If it's a third party component can you share a link or something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you need to show the error and also mention some details like the browser that you are using.